# Conditional Expectation under Transformation of Variables

Tags: probability, transformation, conditional-expectation

Say I have a probability distribution $P_X(x)$ and I am computing the conditional expectation of some function $f(x)$ as :

$$E[f| P>a] = \int_{x=P^{-1}(a)}^{x=\infty} f(x)p_X(x)dx$$

(where $a$ is some number between $0$ and $1$). Note I am abusing notation a bit as follows: $x$ is a vectors which makes $P_X(x)$ a multidimensional distribution, and $p_X(x)$ is the density function corresponding to $P_X(x)$.

Now say there is a function $g$ which maps $y$ to $x$ i.e. $x =g(y)$.
Under this transformation the probability distribution is also transformed as
$$p_X(x)dx = q_Y(y)dy$$

Then my question is can I write the following:

$$E[f | P>a] = \int_{y=Q^{-1}(a)}^{y=\infty} f(g(y))q_Y(y)dy$$

where as before $q_Y(y)$ is the density function corresponding to $Q_Y(y)$.

The main conceptual issue that I am trying to clarify here is:
Someone asks me to compute $E[f | P>a]$ in a region where the probability distribution is above $a$. I somehow come across a function  $g(y)$ and the corresponding $q_Y(y)$ whose density I know. I do not know what $p_X(x)$ is but I do know what $q_Y(y)$ is  (i.e in principal $p_X(x)$ is computable but maybe it is hard to compute). Then the above statement is saying that I do not need to know $p_X(x)$, I can perform the computation in the $y$-space and it will give me $E[f | P>a]$.

Comment: It looks like your left-hand-side is constant in $x$ in the first equation (you "integrate away" $x$ on the rhs). Is this intentional?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, as i was trying to copy and paste from previous expression. corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is whether it is true that 
$$
E[f(X)\mid P(X)>a] = \int_{P^{-1}(a)}^\infty f(x)p_X(x)\, \mathrm dx \stackrel?= \int_{Q^{-1}(a)}^\infty f(y)q_Y(y)\, \mathrm dy
$$
for a substitution $g(x) = y$.

Short answer: **No**. For a counterexample, consider $f(x) = x$ and $a = \infty$. Then

$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} E\bigl[f(X)\mid P(X)>a\bigr]= E[f(X)] = E[X],
$$
which is just the expectation.
Now, if $p_X(x) = (1+x)^2$, a $\operatorname{Pareto(1,1)}$ r.v. and $q_Y(y) = \exp(-y)$ an $\exp(1)$ r.v. then the former has no finite expectation while the latter has an expectation of $1$; a contradiction to (1).

---

You can, however, use substitution of variable to show that

$$
\int_{P^{-1}(a)}^\infty f(x)p(x)\, \mathrm dx = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{Q^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(y)) q(y)\, \mathrm dy,
$$
where $Q^{-1}(a) = g^{-1}(P^{-1}(a))$. This puts restrictions on $g$.

Comment: something is strange about your answer. $a$ is between $[0,1]$ because it is the cumulative probability. So in the first part I think you mean $a=0$ instead of $a=\infty$. In the second part do I need to go via $g^{-1}(P^{-1}(a))$ to compute the value of $Q^{-1}(a)$ ? If $a=95\%$ say, then all I need to compute is the region where $Q^{-1} > 95\%$